# Fastest English dictionary on the web?

Tags: webapp-rec

The content on [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/molasses) is clear and comprehensive... once... it... finishes... loading.

It's even slow if I disable advertising, plus I prefer not to do so as I appreciate that ad-revenue may be important for the services I use.

As I type, it's *still* loading. I'm giving up...

What's the fastest (reasonably detailed) dictionary app on the web?

Comment: [Definr](http://definr.com/)...the site's title says it all. :)

Comment: Uses Wordnet, which isn't all too recent or contentful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [thefreedictionary.com](http://thefreedictionary.com/p/Word) with print layout.

Comment: This seems the best combination of speed and content. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[Ninjawords](http://ninjawords.com/)'s tagline is:

> A really fast dictionary... fast like a ninja.

For comprehensive and relatively fast, try [The Free Dictionary](http://www.tfd.com/). Tagline:

> The world's most comprehensive dictionary

Comment: That is eerily fast. Not massively comprehensive, but it does flip out and kill dictionary.com.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/)? Same caveats and advantages as Wikipedia and should be pretty darn fast.

Comment: I second this recommendation. Wiktionary is a pretty good resource, and very speedy.

Comment: I find Wiktionary invaluable for foreign language study, but when looking up English words I find it too full of foreign words :)

Comment: @Ian Mackinnon: So don't look up the foreign words (-;

Answer (score 3):

I love [wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com). It's fast, covers many obscure words, the examples(usage) are very good. It also has an API. It's brilliant I think.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need a full dictionary but just a short definition, Google with `define:` in the URL.

[define:google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3agoogle)

If you do need a full dictionary, [Google Dictionary](http://www.google.com/dictionary) has already been mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Surprised no one has mentioned the meta dictionary tool:

http://www.onelook.com/?w=fast

It is fast, gives you a short definition, but also looks up the word in 100s of other dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Dictionary](http://www.google.com/dictionary) seems to be good & fast.

Comment: though imperfect.  It is based on statistical analysis, which may give wrong results at times.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you're looking for an etymological dictionary. In that case, http://www.etymonline.com/ is probably your best bet.

Note that with Firefox and Opera, you can set up a custom search, which saves you having to visit the homepage of the site. If you set up `ed`, for example, as your custom search keyword, you can just type `ed dictionary` into the address bar, and be taken directly to [the results page](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=dictionary&searchmode=none).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're not into huge definition lists or synonyms, [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) translates instantaneously. Like, really fast.

Comment: For that matter, plain old Google Search will give you a dictionary definition on single-word queries (assuming it's a real word). With Google Instant active you probably can't get anything faster.

Comment: generally I use it for fairly obscure words and am after a phonetic guide and etymology. A few choice quotes for example use can also be very helpful. Also on the connections where I am even "instantaneous" isn't that fast :)

Answer (score 0):

[dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome, you can do a couple of things:

1. Perhaps you already know about it, but use the [Google Dictionary extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja). With that, you simply double click on a word and meaning pops up.
2. Next, what I've done is completely minimized Merriam Webster and dictionary.com using the Stylebot (stylebot.me) extension. That way, they feel a lot less intrusive and also feel faster.

Here is custom CSS I use for both:

*dictionary.reference.com*: gist.github.com/587652
*merriam-webster.com*: gist.github.com/606237

PS: I couldn't post more than one hyperlink since I'm new here, so excuse me for lack of proper reference links.

Answer (score 0):

[Vocabulary.com's Dictionary](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/) is blazing fast. It calls itself the world's fastest, smartest dictionary and I think they are right.